# iOS development, registering users with iPhone App

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

What is the best method for implementing a user registration process for iOS app? I'm messing around with UserDefaults and have a UserSettingsController, I show the UserSettingsController modally, but I was thinking about checking UserDefaults for a value, if NOT present force them to a registration Controller.

If this sounds right, I'm not sure where to do this check? I was doing it in my "homeviewController" on the didload, but I feel like it should go in the AppDelegate.

I have this in my viewDidLoad on HomeController

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *registered = [defaults objectForKey:@"registered"];
if (registered == nil) {
    NSLog(@"empty");

// I need to do something here.

}
```

I would very much appreciate your input and guidance.

Comment: Could this question be a candidate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handled it:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loggedIn"]) {
        self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    }
    else {
        LogInViewController *loginVC = [[LogInViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LogInViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = loginVC;
        [loginVC release];
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

then I have a call back method, probably best to make it a protocol but could just call it directly when login is successful to

```
- (void)logInComplete {    
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
}
```

Comment: that worked, but I wonder why when I use           

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *fname = [defaults objectForKey:@"firstName"];
    if(fname != nil){
        self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBar;    
    }
    else
    {
        UserViewController *uvc = [[UserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = uvc;
        
    }
and it doesnt work. I'm basically checking if firstname is nil change root view controller, how is mine different?

Comment: firstName must not be getting set in userDefaults. By the way if it is a string it would be better to use stringForKey:

Comment: Yep. You are right, but documentation says...
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Return Value
The object associated with the specified key, or nil if the key was not found.
thanks.